# creating AIML for chatbot to ask questions

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I am creating AIML file for Program-O chatbot and facing a problem.
What I want to do is ask question after question sequentially. Moreover, the questions should be in random order. It is satisfaction assessment test for students and I am experimenting to develop by using chatbot instead of traditional methods.

This is the AIML format I have in mind.

**sample.aiml**

```
<category>
    <pattern>HELLO<bot/></pattern>
    <template>
        <random>
            <li><warm/>Hello there. Do you want to talk about your campus life?</li>
            <li><happy/>Hi. Do you want to talk about your campus life?</li>
            <li><happy/>Goodday. Do you want to talk about your campus life?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>HELLO THERE. DO YOU WANT TO TALK ABOUT CAMPUS LIFE</that>
    <template>
        <random>
            <li>How were the classes?</li>
            <li>Does the teacher give a clear answer?</li>
            <li>Was the teacher come on time?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <that>HOW WERE THE CLASSES</that>
    <template>
        <random>
            <li>Does the teacher give the full and clear explanation?</li>
            <li>What about the material used in the classes?</li>
            <li>What do you think about the courses content?</li>
        </random>
    </template>
</category>
```

The **problem** is that *(asterisk) wildcard is not working well with that  predicate.
Is there any other way to construct the AIML which fulfill my requirement?

Comment: What means "is not working well"? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use the underscore wildcard. In AIML, there are two wildcards - * and _. The underscore wildcard has higher priority then the asterisk.

Comment: Now, in aiml ver=2.0 there are additional wildcards to help with this. One of them being ^. Perhaps worth checking out for anyone hitting this question in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(txt_filename.Text.ToString()).ToString();

        int length = (Int32)text.Length;
        txt_gbox.Text = length.ToString();

        LexicalAnalysis analyzer = new LexicalAnalysis();

        while (text !=)
        {
            text = text.Trim(' ', '\t');
            string token = analyzer.GetNextLexicalAtom(ref text);
            txt_gbox.Text = token;
        }
```

I want to show these token in richtextbox which is txt_gbox but on while loop programe stop....